# collapseable items in an unordered list

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

**Solution:**

Nikhil almost had the answer. In the end I had to make and initiate an empty array for showing the details. I changed

```
return value.searchName.indexOf(this.name.toLowerCase()) != -1 ? value : null;
```

to

```
if (this.name.toLowerCase() == value.name.toLowerCase()) {
    this.showingDetails.push(false);
    return value;
}
else {
    return null;
}
```

and for the rest followed what Nikhil has given me.

**Question:**

I have an unordered list on my website that contains (per list item) a name, a link and a long bit of text.

The list is filled with data from a database. It is thus unknown how many items there will be in the list. I cannot hard-code it and make a `div` for each item.

I was wondering if it is possible to hide the long text per item, and display it when the user clicks a link. 
Right now, I can hide and show text, but clicking 'show' will display the text for all items in the list.

I'm working in Angular/typescript and what I have now is this:

```
<ul class='list-group' *ngFor='#item of Items'>
    <li>
        <hr>
        <p><strong>{{ item.sourceType }}:</strong> <em>{{ item.sourceName }}</em></p>
        <p><strong>Link:</strong> <a target="_blank" href="{{ item.source }}">{{ item.source }}</a></p>
        <p><strong>Details:</strong> <a (click)="showDetails()">{{ showHideTxt }}</a></p>   
        <p style="white-space:pre-wrap" *ngIf="showingDetails">{{ item.details }}</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and in the class:

```
items:Item[] = [];
name:string = "unknown";
foundItems:Item[];
showHideTxt:string = "show";
showingDetails:boolean = false;
itemSubscription:Subscription;

constructor(private itemService:ItemService) 
{
}   

ngOnInit()
{
    this.itemSubscription = this.itemService.getItems()
        .subscribe(
            itemData => this.items = itemData.json(),
            err => console.log(err),
            () =>   this.foundItems = this.items.filter((value)=>{
                        return value.searchName.indexOf(this.name.toLowerCase()) != -1 ? value : null
                    });
        )
    this.name = decodeURI(this.routeParams.get('name'));

    console.log(this.name.toLowerCase());
}

ngOnDestroy()
{
    this.itemSubscription.unsubscribe();
}

showDetails()
{
    this.showingDetails = !this.showingDetails
    this.showingDetails
        ?this.showHideTxt = "hide"
        :this.showHideTxt = "show";
}
```

Comment: you can use a custom pipe to do that, in angular 2+/4/5/6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your component class, create a boolean array of `showingDetails` which stores the visibility state of each list item. `showHideTxt` property is not needed and can be removed.

And in your HTML, pass the index of the list item when calling `showDetails()` method, and in that method, toggle the visibility of the item at that index.

Your final code should look like:

**Component class:**

```
showingDetails = new Array(this.items.length).fill(false);

showDetails(index) {
    this.showingDetails[index] = !this.showingDetails[index];
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<ul class='list-group' *ngFor='let item of items; let i=index'>
    <li>
        <hr>
        <p><strong>{{ item.sourceType }}:</strong> <em>{{ item.sourceName }}</em></p>
        <p><strong>Link:</strong> <a target="_blank" href="{{ item.source }}">{{ item.source }}</a></p>
        <p><strong>Details:</strong> <a (click)="showDetails(i)">{{ showingDetails[i] === true ? 'Hide' : 'Show' }}</a></p>   
        <p style="white-space:pre-wrap" *ngIf="showingDetails[i]">{{ song.details }}</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**EDIT:**

Since HTTP calls are asynchronous, code containing `items` array outside the subscription block are being executed before code inside the subscription block. This is causing `items` array to be `undefined`.

One solution would be to move that code inside the subscription block, like:

```
/* Other code */
...
...
showingDetails: boolean[];


ngOnInit()
{
    this.itemSubscription = this.itemService.getItems()
        .subscribe(
            itemData => this.items = itemData.json(),
            err => console.log(err),
            () =>   {
              this.foundItems = this.items.filter((value)=> {
                 return value.searchName.indexOf(this.name.toLowerCase()) != -1 ? value : null
                    });

               // initializing 'showingDetails' property inside this block
               this.showingDetails = new Array(this.foundItems.length).fill(false);
            }
        )
    this.name = decodeURI(this.routeParams.get('name'));

    console.log(this.name.toLowerCase());
}
```

Comment: I'm now running into the problem that I initiate the list of items in `ngOnInit`. I have tried initiating the boolean array inside and outside `ngOnInit`, but in both cases the 'items' array is undefined. (even though it is not undefined when I fill the array of items). Somehow it can access the 'items' array when filling, but not when later trying to get its length.

Comment: Could you edit the question and post relevant sections of the code? It helps in understanding the problem better.

Comment: Perhaps also important to know: The items array is 'filled' with a subscription. That gets a list of all items (using an http get call), applies a filter and dislays what items are left. My understanding was that the items array would contain those items, but perhaps my understanding of this process is wrong.
I will add the rest of the code.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I saw the code you added. I'll edit my answer to address the problem.

Comment: @WhiteFalcon Take a look at my edited answer and see if it works.

Comment: Even there, 'items' is undefined. I've also tried to add your line of code (and `this.showingDetails.push(false);`) to the `filter` function. This didn't work either (as I was expecting...) I am going to update the website to a newer version of Angular, and may improve other aspects too. If there is an easier way of dealing with this, than that is also an option.

Comment: I'm glad you finally figured it out @WhiteFalcon. Way to go!